# Order type between two sets and bijection?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I want to show that $$ \{1,2\}\times Z_+\ \text{and} \ Z_+ \times\{1,2\}\ \text{have different  order type}$$

If we define $$f(i,j)=(j,i)\ \text{for}\ i\  \text{in }\{1,2\}\ \text{and} \ j\ \text{in}\ Z_+$$

It seems like that this is bijective map between two sets.

However, to show that they are not order isomorphic, how shall I start to show that bijection does not preserve ordering?

It seems like that the way I defined the bijection is not the only way.

I am wondering if there exists any bijection between two sets and that bijection does not preserve order, can I conclude that they have different order type?

Comment: Hint: Consider elements with no immediate predescessor.

Comment: (2,1) on the left has no immediate predescessor?

Comment: Correct. Are there any such on the right?

Comment: (1,1) in the left-hand order also has no immediate predecessor.

Comment: None exists on the right, yes I see. it seems like an isomorphism between two sets in a sense that they have two different structures

Comment: I think that (1.1) has no immediate predecessor but it is the smallest element, so if we assume that there is order isomorphism, then f(1.1) is the smallest element on the right and it does not have immediate predecessor possibly? So, nothing can be concluded?

Comment: Well, the point is that the one on the left has more than one such element, and the other only has one.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity I'm going to use $2$ itself to denote the two-element set $\{0,1\}$ (not a total fiction: this is true in ZF. But you can just take it as abuse of notation).

$2\times \Bbb Z$ is $\Bbb Z + \Bbb Z$, two copies of $\Bbb Z$ laid end to end:
$$
2\times \Bbb Z = \left(\cdots + -1_{0} + 0_{0} + 1_{0} + \cdots\right) \,+\, \left(\cdots + -1_{1} + 0_{1} + 1_{1} + \cdots \,+\, \cdots\right)$
$$

On the other hand, $\Bbb Z \times 2$ is $\Bbb Z$-many copies of $\{0,1\}$, which is 
$$
\Bbb Z \times 2 = \cdots + \left(0_{-1} + 1_{-1}\right) + \left(0_{0} + 1_{0}\right) + \left(0_{1} + 1_{1}\right) + \cdots.
$$
It's easy to find an order-theoretic property that distinguishes between these sets:

$2\times \Bbb Z$ has the property that there are strictly increasing sequences of its elements that are bounded above. An order isomorphism preserves strict increasing sequences and maps upper bounds of their elements to upper bounds of what it maps the elements to. So this same property has to be true of the target ordering. However, in $\Bbb Z \times 2$, no strictly increasing sequence has an upper bound.